# Fetching the current console size

Tags: c, windows, console, console-application

I am wanting to fetch the current console size in rows and columns. Using the [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function I can get a [CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure which has the following:

```
typedef struct _CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO {
  COORD      dwSize;
  COORD      dwCursorPosition;
  WORD       wAttributes;
  SMALL_RECT srWindow;
  COORD      dwMaximumWindowSize;
} CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO;
```

The closest field is the `dwMaximumWindowSize` which as the name suggests fetches the maximum window size. Is there no way I get fetch the current window size (i.e. number of rows and columns)?

Comment: What does `dwSize` output?

Comment: Is that not what the dwSize parameter is?

Comment: Well, you certainly would have thought so! Unfortunately no, dwSize refers to the current buffer size which has little bearing on the window size.

Comment: Because dwSize gets the width and height buffer size.

Comment: Well, you're correct.  The size of the window is in the srWindow parameter.

Comment: @Luke I'm afraid not. The `srWindow` specifies a rectangle that specifies the part of the _buffer_ currently being used on the display - not the actual window size in rows and columns.

Comment: D'oh! Of course... The size of the buffer being used on the display!... Shall just check...

Comment: @Luke Please post an answer and let me slink away with embarrassment quietly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the window is in the `srWindow` field:

> srWindow
>
> A SMALL_RECT structure that contains the console screen buffer coordinates of the upper-left and lower-right corners of the display window.